# Can we set duration for setContentOffset:animated?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to have animation with UICollectionView, so I use the following method,
but it seems that I cannot set the duration.

```
self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: offsetX + 100, y: 0), animated: true)
```

How can I change the animation duration?

Comment: Sometimes wrapping it in an animation block works in cases like these, though I don't know if it will have any effect here.

Answer (score -2):

You should include this code in

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
       // <#code#>
        self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: offsetX + 100, y: 0), animated: true)

    }]
```

Please enter the time you want in place of 5.0(in seconds).

Comment: @iOSGeek it doesn't work... have tried anything else